# Error in Cloudera Cluster installation process?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, apache-pig, cloudera, hadoop-streaming

I have installed Cloudera manager successfully. It shows Currently managed hosts as 127.0.0.1 and it is active.

When I search and install cluster using the cloudera manager after the loads it shows the following error.

```
Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent.
    Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.
    Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager server (check firewall rules).
    Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are free on the host being added.
    Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being added (some of the logs can be found in the installation details).
```

The following image clearly shows the problem while installing my cluster on cloudera manager.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and it turned out the issue was *conveniently* skipping (unfortunately) the *...password-less SSH key ...* step

After several hours breaking my head over it, I realised this.

At the terminal do,

```
ls -al ~/.ssh
```

You must see files like,

```
abc
abc.pub
```

These are you public/private key pairs. [Not necessarily the same names as mine above].The file name you used in [Setting up SSH public/private keys](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html)  step  for your machine.

You need to copy the data in `abc.pub` to a file `authorized_keys` in this same folder. If its not there, create `authorized_keys`.
 Incase you don't have you public/private key pair [see here](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html)

Answer (score 2):

For ubuntu, the problem is usually because of the association of "ubuntu 127.0.1.1." in your /etc/hosts file. For me, after changing it to "ubuntu 127.0.0.1", which is the standard local loopback, I can add the cluster successfully. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this problem for two days. Fixing **/etc/hosts** as suggested by "khoadoan" worked for me.

/etc/hosts was looking like this when I had the problem

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    ubuntu
```

I changed it like this:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    ubuntu
```

Restarted the machine.

```
sudo init 6
```

Launched the Cloudera Manager Admin page. This time the host status was already showing up "Managed = Yes". And I got an additional tab "Currently Managed Hosts(1)", where the local host was listed.